# for loop command with multiple variables

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I am very new to command line and script language, and not so familiar with terms. I will try my best to explain my issue.

I am trying to edit/compress my ebooks in bulk process, and here comes the Calibre.
Calibre is the ebook editing software to make some changes to my epub files.

It's quite feature rich and in most cases easy to use, but only and biggest downside is whenever I edit/covert/read books in the GUI interface I first have to add books in the library, which involves making copy of every file into calibre's predefined directory. and on editor's GUI I can only edit one file at a time.

I have thousands of ebooks to edit, it will take days to do so, it's also bad for my storage space. Big NO NO.

Thankfully, it is possible to compress images in mass on command line interface with the help of useful plugin to asssist with handling bulk files.

```bash
for /r "C:\Users\foldername" %v in (*.epub) do calibre-debug -r "Editor Chains" "Compress Images" "%v" "%v.epub"
```

It works just as expected. it scans all epub files in that folder and its subfolders, and call the plugin to do its job - compress images - and save the output files in the same folder, adding the ".epub" extension to the name of original file name to avoid duplicate.(e.g. `this is a book.epub` --> `this is a book.epub.epub`)

Only problem is I have yet to find a way to save the output files in a different folder, with same file name. maybe there's something I am missing or it's just not possible.

If anyone knows how, please let me know.

I've tried:

```bash
for /r "C:\Users\foldername" %v & "C:\Users\newfoldername" %x in (*.epub) do calibre-debug -r "Editor Chains" "Compress Images" "%v" "%x"
```

... and it obviously failed, haha.

Comment: Perhaps you want something like this: ```for /r "C:\Users\foldername" %g in (*.epub) do @calibre-debug -r "Editor Chains" "Comress Images" "%g" "C:\Users\newfoldername\%~nxg"```. If `"C:\Users\newfoldername"` does not already exist, you'll probably need to ```md "C:\Users\newfoldername"``` first. Please also remember if this is for use in a batch file, _(`.cmd` or `.bat`)_, you'll need to double your `%` characters too, i.e. ```@for /r "C:\Users\foldername" %%g in (*.epub) do @calibre-debug -r "Editor Chains" "Comress Images" "%%g" "C:\Users\newfoldername\%%~nxg"```.

Comment: Agreed! . ALSO take the time to TEST before you accidentally mess up all of your files. `md C:\Users\testing` copy a few files into `C:\Users\testing` try to pick any odd files names, certainly ones with spaces in them, but if you see `$,%,#` etc in a file name, copy one of those for testing as well. **Only test on copies!** Good luck!

Comment: As an additional note, I copied your command to run against each file from your example, despite it using the word `Comress`, which I'd assume should have been `Compress`.